# How do I reformat/clean this drive with lvms on it?

Tags: lvm, mkfs

I have two RAID-10 spans. One I had misconfigured into an lvm-thin. It currently looks like this.

```
sdb                                 8:16   0  1.8T  0 disk
├─sdb1                              8:17   0  1.8T  0 part
├─data2-data2_tmeta               253:0    0 15.8G  0 lvm
│ └─data2-data2-tpool             253:2    0  1.8T  0 lvm
│   ├─data2-data2                 253:3    0  1.8T  0 lvm
│   └─data2-vm--109--disk--0      253:4    0  700G  0 lvm
└─data2-data2_tdata               253:1    0  1.8T  0 lvm
  └─data2-data2-tpool             253:2    0  1.8T  0 lvm
    ├─data2-data2                 253:3    0  1.8T  0 lvm
    └─data2-vm--109--disk--0      253:4    0  700G  0 lvm
```

I want to format all of /dev/sdb so I can setup a new logical volume group.
But when I do a mkfs.ext4 on it, linux yells at me:
When I try to format it with mkfs.ext4 I get the error:

```
/dev/sdb is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!
```

I have this running on proxmox, and proxmox see's the disk, but I can't seem to do anything with it.
[image: dev/sdb]

When I run lvs or pvs I don't see it show up with any logical  volumes or as a physical volume group. I'd really not like to shut the server down in order to initialize this span, is there anything I can do through cli?

Thanks much.

Comment: what is the result of `pvs` and `vgs` ? (If no one is "holding" /dev/sdb, use ` fdisk /dev/sdb`  to delete partition).

Comment: Hey Archemar, sdb and its lvm partitions were not showing up when doing a pvs and vgs or lvs command. This was a poweredge dell server which I had installed OMSA (Dell openmanage) on, fortunately I was able to remotely log into it, and re-initialize that particular virtual disk raid10 span via dell open manage and the raid card. That second span was just additional storage and didnt hold any important partitions. After re-initializing the disks, I was able to rebuild a partition on /dev/sdb and then turn it into a new LVM, now it is functioning properly. Strange problem nonetheless.

Comment: I had in fact deleted the partitions on it, but when I was doing an fdisk it wasnt seeing the lvm partitions. fdisk was telling me there were no partitions on /dev/sdb even though the lsblk command showed the structure you see above. As I mentioned above, I just gave up and found a way to re-initialize the RAID10 span and just rebuild the LVM.